# Javascript: Converting between number ranges, keeping the correct ratio

Tags: javascript, math, range

I have two sets of pixel coordinates that represent a bounding box:

```
top left: 
x: 19757934
y: 25240264

bottom right: 
x: 19759195
y: 25240776
```

I need to convert another point's coordinates, that are on a different number range into the above range, maintaining the original ratio (to find out where this point is located within the bounding box).

```
x: 423
y: 142
```

Comment: what is the "different number range"?

Comment: I meant to say number scale...the original bounding box coordinates are on a different number scale than the point coordinates. I need to found out the point's coordinates on the original number scale.

Comment: And what's the relation between the two ranges/scales?

Comment: The first bounding box coordinates are the div boundaries pixel coordinates on a full tile map. The point coordinates are in relation to the div (containing the tile map) on screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is a box the user clicks on, which does something to a "result" box somewhere else, like a scaled down box.

```
var from_coords = {x1:50,y1:80,x2:150,y2:180};
var to_coords = {x1:200,y1:230,x2:400,y2:430};
function translate(input_coords) { // input_coords = {x:123,y:123}
    return {
        x:to_coords.x1+(input_coords.x-from_coords.x1)*(to_coords.x2-to_coords.x1)/(from_coords.x2-from_coords.x1),
        y:to_coords.y1+(input_coords.y-from_coords.y1)*(to_coords.y2-to_coords.y1)/(from_coords.y2-from_coords.y1)
    };
}

console.log(translate({x:123,y:123}); // outputs {x:346,y:316}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, the first bounding box is 1261x512, making width/height = 2.462890

I'm calling the "different number range" a box with width W2 and height H1. If W2/H2 is not equal to 2.462890, this whole exercise is pointless because you need to rescale the width or height.

If Top Left of the second box is not (0,0), move all points to (0,0) then move back after doing the computations. I'm assuming (0,0) is the top left corner.

So, you just need a ratio on one dimension. Find out what 423/W2 is, then multiply by 1261. This gives you the X-offset, which you add to 19757934.

With the ratio measured, for Y we just multiply: 512 * 423/W2, then add to 25240264.

```
Example: second box is 985x400. Ratio = 423/985 = 0.429.
0.429 * 1261 = 541; 541 + 19757934 = 19758475.
for Y: 0.429 * 512 = 219; 219 + 25240264 = 25240483.
```